# Restrict panning and zoom on Here Maps 3.0

Tags: here-api

I generated a map with Here maps JS Api 3.0. I want to restrict the zoom to a min/max value and the panning to a given rectangle. Is there a way to do that? 
for example:

```
map.setMinZoom(4);
map.setMaxZoom(14);
map.setPanRestriction(rectangle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you're trying to restrict the viewport to where you now have you image overlay...

The easiest way is to listen to view model and and viewport updates similar the other example:
[Custom map overlay heremaps js api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406396/custom-map-overlay-heremaps-js-api-v3)

Now you can look at the map's center coordinate and see if it is within the boundaries you wish to display. If not, set it to within the boundaries. Something along those lines may work for you:

```js
var bounds = new H.geo.Rect(45, -45, -45, 45);

map.getViewModel().addEventListener('sync', function() {
  var center = map.getCenter(),
      adjustLat,
      adjustLng;
  if (!bounds.containsPoint(center)) {
    if (center.lat > bounds.getTop()) {
      adjustLat = bounds.getTop();
    } else if (center.lat < bounds.getBottom()) {
      adjustLat = bounds.getBottom();
    } else {
      adjustLat = center.lat;
    }
    if (center.lng < bounds.getLeft()) {
      adjustLng = bounds.getLeft();
    } else if (center.lng > bounds.getRight()) {
      adjustLng = bounds.getRight();
    } else {
      adjustLng = center.lng;
    }
    map.setCenter({
      lat: adjustLat,
      lng: adjustLng
    });
  }
});

//Debug code to visualize where your restriction is
map.addObject(new H.map.Rect(bounds));
```